# How do you use preload links for CSS containing only @font-face?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm declaring preload links for a CSS file containg **ONLY** `@font-face` rules.

Should I add `<link rel="preload" href="styles.css" as="style">` **as="style"** or `<link rel="preload" href="styles.css" as="font">` **as="font"**?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are attempting to load `styles.css` which is a style sheet, you should use `as="style"`

If you were loading a font it would look something like this `<link rel="preload" href="fonts/some-webfont.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">`

If you have a look at this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content you can see that there are a number of different types of content that can be pre-loaded using this technique.

Comment: Should the use preload links for *both* the css file and the font URLs it contains?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Good question...maybe you can ask it ;o)  I am not sure, I suspect that pre-loading the CSS will also pre-load the font it contains, but some testing would verify that.